# Python/Scrapy: How to determine if a page is html or not?

Tags: python, html, scrapy

I need to determine if a page downloaded by Scrapy spider is html or not. The site I wish the spider to crawl has a combination of pdf and html links. Hence, if it comes across a pdf file, it'll put the response through a PDFReader, else it'll read the html file as is. This is part of my code, but it's not working:

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "spyder_OLD"
    allowed_domains = ['doc.scrapy.org']
    start_urls = ['https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/index.html']

    def parse(self, response):
        ct = response.headers.get("content-type", "").lower()
        return ct
```

I output the results of the spider to a .csv file, but it's always empty. Just having `ct = response.headers` outputs the entire header information, which is useless. What do I do?

**EDIT:**
I have finally managed to return a dictionary, but still can't extract the relevant information:

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "spyder_OLD"
    allowed_domains = ['doc.scrapy.org']
    start_urls = ['https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/index.html']

    def parse(self, response):
        ct = {"content-type": response.headers.get("content-type", "").lower()}
        return ct["content-type"]
```

Outputting the above to a .csv file still returns a blank file, though `output ct` returns a .csv file with two lines: `content-type` and `text/html`. How do I extract the 'html' text part of the answer only?

Comment: Not sure if it'll be `Content-Type:` 

Comment: No, that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scrapy expects you to return an item from your parse method. It can be a dict or an [Item object](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html#topics-items).

If you are interested in the Content-Type:

```
def parse(self, response):
    ct = response.headers.get("content-type", "").lower()
    return {'content-type': ct}
```

Scrapy has a really nice tutorial. It is worth to take a moment to follow it: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html

**EDIT:**

You can find the HTML code in the `response.text` property. But usually, you will want just a piece of this code. So, the better approach is using **selectors**. E.g, to get just the text inside the snippet `<h1>Hello world</h1>`, you can use:

```
title = response.css('h1::text').get()
return {'title': title}
```

Take some time to read the [documentation page about selectors](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html). It worths the investment.

Comment: Hi, thank you for that, but how do I return just the 'html' part of the answer?

Comment: Hi, that’s well and good - but how do I get the title data in the {‘title’: title} dictionary? The normal python method of dictionary[‘title’] does not work.

Comment: It will become a column in the export file. Eg. By running `scrapy runspider  spiyder.py -o items.csv`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the lxml module and import the text as html.  If it parses it successfully then it's HTML.

```
from lxml import etree
```

I'm on a phone so I can't give you a full example.   etree.parse is the method you want.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is still around. But it sounds like builtwith module may be useful to you?

It shows you the various javascript frameworks, web frameworks, and web servers  being implemented. You can Google the web frameworks and determine if they are used to dynamically load content.

You can: pip install builtwith

https://pypi.org/project/builtwith/1.3.3/